# AWS OpenSearch with Exclusion List

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm looking to run an [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/docs/1.2/opensearch/rest-api/search/) / [ElasticSearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/searching.html) query using the Search API. How do I run a search, but exclude specific documents from the results?

For example, I have a movies index containing the names of different movies that are available and you can run a search on the name:

```
GET /movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Night"
    }
  }
}
```

However, say the user has already indicated that they don't like specific movies, such as "Boogie Nights" and "Aladdin." I'd like to be able to provide a list of movies to exclude in the search. Must I run the search first, and then exclude the items from the results after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the movies to remove you can to use [must_not query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with filter query.

Comment: Thank you so much - I was searching everywhere for this! Will accept this as the answer.